# Override the styles of Google recaptcha

Tags: css, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I have an HTML/Bootstrap page page where i am using google recaptcha V2. 
I have a style class css file which is working(i am having other styles working through this css).
I am trying to override the background color of "I am not Robot" so i added following line in  CSS file:

```
.rc-anchor-light {
background : blue;
color : red;
}
```

These are not final colors just to see if this works

but its not working, even when i inspect the element i see the rc-anchor-light entries coming from styles__ltr.css and not my css file.
Where am i wrong?

Comment: Try to use `!important` behind the css declarations. So like this `background: blue !important;`

Comment: did'nt work even with !important. it is not picking from local css file for rc-anchor tags, picking from gstatic.com when i see in chrome developer tool

Answer (score 0):

you can override by giving more css specificity like

```
div .rc-anchor-light {
  background : blue;
  color : red;
}
```

this will have more weight than your selector

you can learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

if it doesnt work then your last option is adding `!important`

Comment: Did'nt work. added div in front of style class in css but still picking the style class from gstatic.com